# Wordpress dynamic sidebar widget title customization

Tags: wordpress

I want to customize the h3.widget-title to something like this `"<span color="black"> This is a </span><span color="white">widget title </a>`

So that it will display out in different color. 
I tried to look into functions.php, widgets.php, but I can't figure out where is the file that print out the dynamic_sidebar('primary-widget-area'). I found the `"<ul> <li>"` in themesfolder/functions.php but it didn't print out the widget title.

I only need to do this for primary widget. Where do I find the code that prints out the primary sidebar items and title?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

open up the twentyten themes function.php file in your text editor
do a ctrl+f to search for "primary-widget-area"
within this section is the

```
'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
'after_title' => '</h3>',
```

then simply add your code within that h3 tag..ie:

```
'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title"><span color="black">This is a</span>',
'after_title' => '<span color="white">widget title </span></h3>',
```

save and close then upload 
you should see the changes after you refresh. 
hope that helps you somewhat..

Comment: Hi Marty, thanks for your reply. However in the theme I could not find where it echos out the "This is a widget title" :)

Answer (score 0):

This all depends on the theme it is and how it was coded.
At minimum you will need to provide the theme name with a link to a public download so we can see the code.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I'm using the default theme in wordpress, called "twenty ten" http://2010dev.wordpress.com/2010/06/18/twenty-ten-available/